# Access Lambda Tmp folder

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to employ ClamAV into Layered AWS Lambda. I downloads file from s3 for clamav to scan and put that into /tmp folder but when I try to access it from another process it says file. Code:

```
var s3Object = await _amazonS3Client.GetObjectAsync(s3Event.Bucket.Name, s3Event.Object.Key);

            if (!s3Object.WithScanStatus(ObjectScanStatus.InProgress))
            {
                _logger.LogWarning(@$"Trying to scan already processed asset. Name: {s3Event.Object.Key}. Bucket: {s3Event.Bucket.Name}");
                return s3Object.GetScanStatus();
            }

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream($"/tmp/{s3Object.Key}", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                s3Object.ResponseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }

            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "clamscan",
                    Arguments = $" --database=/opt/var/lib/clamav/ /tmp/{s3Object.Key}",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };

            process.Start();
```

So in arguments $" --database=/opt/var/lib/clamav/ /tmp/{s3Object.Key}" while accessing /tmp/{s3Object.Key} error is thrown

> File not found at specified location (implies on /tmp/{s3Object.Key} path)

Maybe someone experienced that issue
Any help is appreciated

Comment: And what's the value of the `Arguments` property before the process starts? Is it what you expected?

Comment: Are you sure it's not saying that it couldn't find `clamscan`? Is the error an exception, something you got on stderr/stdout, ...?

Comment: That's the value I set. The only problem is that path mentioned over there seems to be wrong @madreflection

Comment: I didn't ask you to describe the value, I asked for the value.

Comment: ClamAv is found and is ready to scan file by path, but for some reason path is not reachable from process while it IS reachable from lambda code itself. After that ClamAv gives summary with no scanned files count

Comment: Does `s3Object.Key` contain a slash or space character in the name?

Comment: @AnonCoward Not, it contains name.extension with no slashes